# select2 with knockout change minimuminputlength dynamically

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2, custom-binding

I am using Select2 control with knockout and I have a special requirement where I need to set the minimumInputLength option of the Select2 control dynamically based on the length of the options in the select2 combobox. For example if I have 100 options, I need to set the minimumInputLength to 2 and if its less than 100, I need to set it to nothing (or 0).

I tried the following options. select2Combobox here is a custombinding I created.

1) Have a ko Computed Property (bound to the minimumInputLength setting) which will return 2 or 0 based on the length of the observableArray that the select2 is bound to. Here TypeAheadMinInputLength is my computed property.

```
select2Combobox: { select2Options: { width: '100%', minimumInputLength: TypeAheadMinInputLength}, data: TypeaheadData}
```

2) Bind the minimumInputLength setting with a function call which again returns 2 or 0 based on the length of input array that the function is provided with.

```
select2Combobox: { select2Options: { width: '100%', minimumInputLength: getTypeAheadMinInputLength(TypeaheadData())}, data: TypeaheadData}
```

Any suggestions

Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely want to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) this out :)!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it this can help, but you can dynamicaly update the value of minimumInputLength for a given select2 by updating this internal dict. it is hackish, but it work:

```
$('#id_of_select').data("select2").opts.minimumInputLength = 0
```

so, it won't be select2 that will compute the value of minimumInputLength, but you can add a change event to you form and update the select2 widget each time it is needed